# Mocked function not being called in test using Jest to test react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

My test for the error handling in a react application doesn't work and I'm not sure why. The code I'm testing is in main.js and when I test the functionality in the browser by having the api send back an error response it works. I have also checked that the code under test gets to the right "case 404" code block when being tested using console.log calls, so the problem appears to be in the mocking of displayErrorModal.

```
//main.js (code to be tested)
import React from 'react'
import { SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG, FORBIDDEN, NOT_FOUND, NO_RESPONSE, 
REQUEST_FAILED } from './util/error-message-types'
import displayErrorModal from './util/display-error-modal'
import { get } from 'axios'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import App from './app'
const patientId = window.requestParameters.patient_id

get('/api/v1/patients/' + patientId + '/views/multi-episode-summary', 
{
patientId
}).then( //do some stuff
).then( // do some stuff
).catch((error) => {
if (error.response) { //response status code not 2xx
    switch (error.response.status) {
        case 403:
            displayErrorModal('Error', FORBIDDEN)
            break;
        case 404:
            displayErrorModal('Error', NOT_FOUND)
            break;
        case 500:
        default:
            displayErrorModal('Error', SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG)
            break;
    }
} else if (error.request) {//no response received
    displayErrorModal('Error', NO_RESPONSE)
} else {//error in making request
    displayErrorModal('Error', REQUEST_FAILED)
}
})

// display-error-modal.js within util folder
import ErrorModal from '../../../error-modal'
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

export default (headerText, bodyText) => {
    return render(
        <ErrorModal
            header={headerText}
            body={bodyText}
        />,
        document.getElementById('multiple-episode-view-app')
    )
}

// main.test.js within a __tests__ folder
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import displayErrorModal from '../util/display-error-modal'
import { SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG, FORBIDDEN, NOT_FOUND, NO_RESPONSE, 
REQUEST_FAILED } from '../util/error-message-types'

const { it, expect } = global

jest.mock('axios')
jest.mock('../util/display-error-modal')

describe('Multi Episode Summary App', () => {
    it('displays error modal for patient not found', () => {
        window.requestParameters = { patient_id: 100019 }
        const errorResponse = new Error('Patient not found.')
        errorResponse.response = { status: 404 }
        axios.get.mockRejectedValue(errorResponse)
        require('../main')
        expect(displayErrorModal).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Error', NOT_FOUND)
    })
 })
```

When I run the test it fails with the message "Expected mock function to have been called with: ...But it was not called."

Comment: Can the `axios.get` call in `main.js` be wrapped in an exported function?  That would make testing this a lot easier.

Comment: I did try putting all the stuff in main.js in a wrapper function that was exported and imported into the test (and calling the function directly at bottom of main.js) -  but testing then got in a mess with window.requestParams being undefined. I'm new to React and ES6 so might not be doing things the right way - any pointers gratefully received!